# Send Notifications to All Admins

Tags: comments, admin, email, user-registration, notifications

I want to, hopefully without a plugin, get and loop through all admin accounts and notify each admin when a comment has been posted or a user has registered, etc. I tried to look into this but all the solutions pointed to plugins and all the plugins are either bulky or outdated which totes sucks. Is there a nice little filter that someone knows about where I can hook into notifications and send the notification to each / every administrator?

Comment: There is plugin [Better Notifications for WordPress](https://pl.wordpress.org/plugins/bnfw/) that allow to send emails on various actions.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a nice little filter that someone knows about where I can
>   hook into notifications and send the notification to each / every
>   administrator?

There is :

> `comment_post`
>       Runs just after a comment is saved in the database. Action function arguments: comment ID, approval status ("spam", or 0/1 for
>   disapproved/approved).
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Comment.2C_Ping.2C_and_Trackback_Actions

And `user_register` which...

> ...allows you to access data for a new user immediately after they are
>   added to the database. The user id is passed to hook as an argument.
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register

As far as...

> Does anybody have an idea of where I can look to find this answer or
>   solve this problem?

- [The Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org)
- [The source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/)
- [Google](http://www.google.com)

And [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=), of course.